# Bringing a second column of data into Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have picked up a project that a prior DBA built before in Access 2010. Currently the coding builds the report, then outputs it in PDF format. Below is the coding in it's current form:

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [Portfolio Code] FROM [General] ORDER BY [Portfolio Code];", dbOpenSnapshot)

    Do While Not rst.EOF
        strRptFilter = "[Portfolio Code] = " & Chr(34) & rst![Portfolio Code] & Chr(34)

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Main Report", acFormatPDF, "O:\Annual Review\AnnualReviewReport" & "\" & rst![Portfolio Code] & ".pdf"
        DoEvents
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is bring in data from another column in the `[General]` table from the same row that the [Portfolio Code] is in (it is a name associated with the portfolio ID). The reason is so that I can have the pdf files get sorted into directories by name, e.g.

```vb
"O:\Annual Report\AnnualReviewReport\ & [Name] & "\" & [Portfolio Code] & ".pdf"
```

Is there a way to add the `[Name]` field into the `rst` (the name would not be `DISTINCT`, only the Portfolio Code. I am fairly new at this, so please go easy.

Below is the updated script:

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [Portfolio Code], [Trustee 1] FROM [General] ORDER BY [Portfolio Code];", dbOpenSnapshot)

    Do While Not rst.EOF
        strRptFilter = "[Portfolio Code] = " & Chr(34) & rst![Portfolio Code] & Chr(34)

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Main Report", acFormatPDF, "O:\Annual Review\AnnualReviewReport" & "\" & rst![Trustee 1] & "\" & rst![Portfolio Code] & " - " & rst![Trustee 1] & ".pdf"
        DoEvents
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the recordset to contain unique combinations of *[Portfolio Code]* and *[Name]*?  If so, use `SELECT DISTINCT [Portfolio Code], [Name] FROM ...`  If that is not what you want, please show us a brief sample of data from *[General]* and the results you want for your recordset query based on those sample data.

Comment: Hi HansUp, Thank you for that. For some reason I was assuming it was going to be something more labor intense. It is now pulling the data needed, but ends if the sub folder with the [Name] isn't already there. I will include the code below, is there a way have the sub directory created if it's not already there?

Comment: Yes, review the *MkDir Statement* topic in Access' built in help system.  But I think you have more work ahead than you may realize.  *strRptFilter* is not used, or even declared.  Add `Option Explicit` to your module's Declarations section (it's at the top).  Then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix whatever the compiler complains about and try compile again.  Repeat until no more compile errors.  Decide what you want to do with *strRptFilter*.

Comment: Thank you! All up and running perfectly!